# html_entity_decode возвращает строку в <p>

Tags: php

html_entity_decode возвращает строку в p, а мне нужно чтобы она не была обернута в тэг p. Как можно это сделать? Потому как хочу на этот

повесить класс. Если можно сделать так, чтобы возвращала строку с

классом, то буду благодарен!

Comment: Не верю. Код в студию. И входные данные

Comment: это в opencart, когда в админке пишешь текст, а он выводится на страницу